# pandas summarize by count_values as rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to summarize some data by their categories in different columns in a dataframe. This is the data.

```
         feature1  feature2  featurem
brand1   good      none      good
brand2   bad       good      bad
brand..  none      none      good
brandn   good      none      none
```

I would like to have a table that shows me how many from [good,bad,none] I have per feature. So that would tell me how many brands have good in feature 1, bad in feature 1 and none in feature 1 and so on.

I know, for instance, that with

```
df["feature1"].value_counts()
```

I can get such values for each feature separately, but I would like to add it to a new dataframe where I have all the features. How can I do this?

A resulting table would look like this:

[image]

Comment: please don't put images of data(it cannot be copied) , instead post them as text so people can replicate your question

Comment: Well, I did it. But the data is random, it was just to exemplify what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, using `apply` and passing `pd.Series.value_counts`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature '+str(i):np.random.choice(['Good','Bad','none'], 20) for i in range(1,10)})

df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
```

Output:

```
      feature 1  feature 2  feature 3  feature 4  feature 5  feature 6  \
Bad           6         12          6         10          6          4   
Good          6          2          8          5          6          9   
none          8          6          6          5          8          7   

      feature 7  feature 8  feature 9  
Bad           3          6          7  
Good          3          6          4  
none         14          8          9
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but it might be worth separating the random-choice df creation step from the apply that actually answers the question to prevent confusion

Comment: Wow, it was quite easy. Thank you! I am looking into the apply function. by default it applies this to each row (axis=0). Thanks!

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy Actually, `apply` gets each column from the dataframe and applies a function by default.

Answer (score 4):

This is `melt` + `crosstab`

```
m = df.melt()
pd.crosstab(m['value'], m['variable'])
```

```
variable  feature 1  feature 2  feature m
value
bad               1          0          1
good              2          1          2
none              1          3          1
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, could serve also for changing data into one-hot encoding format. Thank you